# Airflow Snowflake Operator Error - AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'sfqid'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow, mwaa

I've recently upgraded our MWAA instance from Airflow 2.2.2 to 2.4.3 but i'm now getting the below error whenever I use the [SnowflakeCheckOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-snowflake/3.0.0/_api/airflow/providers/snowflake/operators/snowflake/index.html#airflow.providers.snowflake.operators.snowflake.SnowflakeCheckOperator) or [get_first](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.14/_api/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook/index.html#airflow.hooks.dbapi_hook.DbApiHook.get_first) function (which the Snowflake python connector inherits from dbapi_hook).

```
query_id = cur.sfqid
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'sfqid'
```

What's odd is I don't get this error when using the SnowflakeOperator or the run function (dbapi_hook).

Below is my test DAG code, requirements.txt, and errors:-

#### DAG

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.snowflake.operators.snowflake import SnowflakeCheckOperator


with DAG(
    "TEST_DAG",
    schedule_interval="*/10 * * * *",
    start_date=datetime(2023, 9, 29),
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
        
        # Check to see if a Snowflake table contains this DAG name.
        check_snowflake_table = SnowflakeCheckOperator(
            task_id="check_snowflake_table",
            snowflake_conn_id="snowflake_conn-non-live",
            sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DEV_MONITORING.NZO_STATE.TBL_DAG_MESSAGE_QUEUE WHERE DAG_NAME = 'TEST_DAG'",
        )
```

#### ✏️  Log

```
[2023-09-29, 17:43:54 UTC] {{sql.py:780}} INFO - Executing SQL check: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DEV_MONITORING.NZO_STATE.TBL_DAG_MESSAGE_QUEUE WHERE DAG_NAME = 'TEST_DAG'
[2023-09-29, 17:43:54 UTC] {{base.py:71}} INFO - Using connection ID 'snowflake_conn-non-live' for task execution.
[2023-09-29, 17:43:54 UTC] {{connection.py:329}} INFO - Snowflake Connector for Python Version: 3.2.0, Python Version: 3.10.8, Platform: Linux-4.14.322-244.536.amzn2.x86_64-x86_64-with-glibc2.26
[2023-09-29, 17:43:54 UTC] {{connection.py:1069}} INFO - This connection is in OCSP Fail Open Mode. TLS Certificates would be checked for validity and revocation status. Any other Certificate Revocation related exceptions or OCSP Responder failures would be disregarded in favor of connectivity.
[2023-09-29, 17:43:54 UTC] {{connection.py:1087}} INFO - Setting use_openssl_only mode to False
[2023-09-29, 17:43:55 UTC] {{cursor.py:804}} INFO - query: [ALTER SESSION SET autocommit=False]
[2023-09-29, 17:43:55 UTC] {{cursor.py:817}} INFO - query execution done
[2023-09-29, 17:43:55 UTC] {{cursor.py:959}} INFO - Number of results in first chunk: 1
[2023-09-29, 17:43:55 UTC] {{snowflake.py:328}} INFO - Running statement: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DEV_MONITORING.NZO_STATE.TBL_DAG_MESSAGE_QUEUE WHERE DAG_NAME = 'TEST_DAG', parameters: None
[2023-09-29, 17:43:55 UTC] {{cursor.py:804}} INFO - query: [SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DEV_MONITORING.NZO_STATE.TBL_DAG_MESSAGE_QUEUE WHERE DAG_NA...]
[2023-09-29, 17:43:55 UTC] {{cursor.py:817}} INFO - query execution done
[2023-09-29, 17:43:55 UTC] {{cursor.py:959}} INFO - Number of results in first chunk: 1
[2023-09-29, 17:43:55 UTC] {{snowflake.py:338}} INFO - Statement execution info - COUNT(*)
[2023-09-29, 17:43:55 UTC] {{connection.py:659}} INFO - closed
[2023-09-29, 17:43:55 UTC] {{connection.py:665}} INFO - No async queries seem to be running, deleting session
[2023-09-29, 17:43:55 UTC] {{taskinstance.py:1851}} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers/common/sql/operators/sql.py", line 781, in execute
    records = self.get_db_hook().get_first(self.sql, self.parameters)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers/common/sql/hooks/sql.py", line 264, in get_first
    return self.run(sql=sql, parameters=parameters, handler=fetch_one_handler)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers/snowflake/hooks/snowflake.py", line 341, in run
    query_id = cur.sfqid
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'sfqid'
```

#### Requirements.txt

```
apache-airflow[amazon,celery,ftp,http,imap,sqlite,mysql,opsgenie]==2.4.3
gnupg==2.3.1
xmltodict
pydantic
setuptools
pipenv
apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==3.0.0
apache-airflow-providers-common-sql==1.7.2
sqlparse==0.4.2
snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.5.0
snowflake-connector-python==3.2.0
apache-airflow-providers-http
apache-airflow-providers-slack
apache-airflow-providers-slack[http]
```

I've checked for package conflicts, upgraded the connector etc. As mentioned I can connect fine to Snowflake and run SQL queries, but some functions have stopped working because it can't find the `sfqid`... But when I use the [run](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.14/_api/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook/index.html#airflow.hooks.dbapi_hook.DbApiHook.run) function It works fine and It even prints:-

```
[2023-09-29, 17:16:28 UTC] {{snowflake.py:343}} INFO - Snowflake query id: 01af512c-0202-dc1e-0001-8052018e474a
```

They've not depreciated the functions i'm using, so i'm really stuck!

Answer (score 1):

Just posting my fix here incase anyone else runs into this issue. I think the issue was a package conflict, though it's very unclear which one and why it was only breaking certain Snowflake Operator functions.

I just updated the `requirements.txt` file to use the 'package extras' handler provided by Airflow/external providers.

It unfortunately means we lose the ability to selectively upgrade packages for when we want to use new features, and these 'package extras' are essentially black boxes where we don't know specifically what modules are being used.

**New requirements file:-**

```
--constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.4.3/constraints-3.10.txt"
apache-airflow[amazon,celery,ftp,http,imap,sqlite,mysql,opsgenie,slack,snowflake]==2.4.3
pydantic
pipenv
```

**Key changes being:-**

- Debulking by removing packages that weren’t being referenced in our repo
- Moving Slack and Snowflake packages into the apache-airflow package extras handler for 2.4.3
- Adding the constraints file for Airflow 2.4.3 and Python 3.10

**Resources:-**

[Installing Python dependencies - Amazon Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/working-dags-dependencies.html)

[Reference for package extras — Airflow Documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.5.1/extra-packages-ref.html)